# Tone down the bracket match highlighting in LaTeX mode

Tags: latex, font-lock

The LaTeX highlighting is great, but I don't like the way every bracket pair is highlighted — and in such a garish colour. Any thoughts on how to tone this down a bit?

[image: Bracket highlighting]

Comment: It might help if you specified what mode(s) you have active in your TeX buffers for this highlighting to occur. E.g. I cannot reproduce it in my setup, using just auctex.

Comment: Actually this doesn't seem to be occurring any more. No idea why it happened or why it stopped… Apologies